How open directly .desktop files with Type=llink into chrome or edge browsers on Ubuntu 22.04
I have a Google Drive folder mounting in my home folder by google-drive-ocamlfuse. The standard configuration for google-drive-ocamlfuse is left Google Doc files like .gdoc, .gform etc. as a .desktop files with Type=link in the mounting home folder.
If I open nautilus and double click those files, it is expected xdg-open can open that files correctly, i.e., in the standard browser as a google doc file.
If I configure Firefox as standard browser, I can open those files correctly in the browser as Google Drive Web page would do.
But, if I configure Chrome or Edge browsers as standard browser, they act like an unknown file, trying download them.
The question is: there is a way to configure Chrome and Edge to do the same way as Firefox do?
uname output: 6.2.0-36-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC x86_64 GNU/Linux
lsb_release output: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, codename: jammy
gnome env:
Edge e Chrome installed from .deb downloaded from respective websites
Firefox is native.

Honestly I do not see anything to fix. The different browsers simply work differently.

Yes. But there is some config to Chrome or Edge to open the link inside and not the .desktop file?
